# passport.authenticate is not working in passport.js?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Everyone I'm beginner in NodeJs. I try to implement local passport implementation.**passport.authenticate('register')** is not calling **passport.use('register')** middleware. like sameway **passport.authenticate('login')** also is not working.I have attached the code.Can anyone fix the bug...Thanks in advance....

```html
config/passport.js:

const LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;

const User=require('../models/user');

console.log(`Outside  passport`);
module.exports=(passport)=>{

    console.log(`Inside passport`);
    passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
        console.log(`SerializeUser:${user}`);
        done(null,user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
        console.log(`Deserialize User:${id}`);
        User.findById(id,function(err,user){
            done(err,user);
        });
    });
    
     console.log(`Above register...`);
     
     passport.use('register',new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField:'email',
        passwordField:'password',
        passReqToCallback:true
     },function(req,email,password,done){
         console.log(`Abovefind...`);
        User.findOne({email:email},function(err,user){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }
            else if(user){
                return done(null,false,req.flash('registerMessage',{message:'User already exist'})); 
            }
            else{
               var newuser=new user();
               newuser.email=email,
               newuser.password=newuser.generateHash(password);
               console.log(newuser);
            }
            newuser.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                return done(null,newuser);
            });
        });
     }));


    passport.use('login',new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField:'email',
        passwordField:'Password',
        passReqToCallback:true
    },function(req,email,password,done){
        User.findOne({email:email},function(err,user){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }
            else if(!user){
                return done(null,false,req.flash('loginMessage',{message:'Incorrect Username'}));
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null,false,req.flash('loginMessage',{message:'Incorrect Password'}));
            }
            return done(null,user);
        });
    }));

}

models/user.js

const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt');

const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String
    }
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash=(password)=>{
    const p=bcrypt.hashSync(password,bcrypt.genSaltSync(10),null);
    console.log(`Hash password: ${p}`);
    return p;
}

userSchema.methods.validPassword=(hashpassword)=>{
    console.log(`Given hash password: ${hashpassword}`);
    const op=bcrypt.compareSync(hashpassword,this.password);
    console.log(`Decode password: ${op}`);
    return op;
}

module.exports=mongoose.model('people',userSchema);


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

routes/routes/js:

 app.post('/register',passport.authenticate('register',{
        successRedirect:'/profile',
        failureRedirect:'/register',
        failureFlash:true 
    }));
    
    
 app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('login',{
        successRedirect:'/profile',
        failureRedirect:'/login',
        failureFlash:true
 }));
```

Comment: what error you are getting? app.js? db.js? or simply refer to
https://github.com/arizafar/Passport-Authentication

Comment: Thanks...for your reference...